# Display COUNT(*) for every week instead of every day

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Let us say that I have a table with `user_id` of `Int32` type and `login_time` as `DateTime` in `UTC` format. 
 `user_id` is not unique, so `SELECT user_id, login_time FROM some_table;` gives following result:

```
┌─user_id─┬──login_time─┐
│    1    │  2021-03-01 │
│    1    │  2021-03-01 │
│    1    │  2021-03-02 │
│    2    │  2021-03-02 │
│    2    │  2021-03-03 │
└─────────┴─────────────┘
```

If I run `SELECT COUNT(*) as count, toDate(login_time) as l FROM some_table GROUP BY l` I get following result:

```
┌─count───┬──login_time─┐
│    2    │  2021-03-01 │
│    2    │  2021-03-02 │
│    1    │  2021-03-03 │
└─────────┴─────────────┘
```

I would like to reformat the result to show `COUNT` on a weekly level, instead of every day, as I currently do.
My result for the above example could look something like this:

```
┌──count──┬──year─┬──month──┬─week ordinal┐
│    5    │  2021 │    03   │       1     │
│    0    │  2021 │    03   │       2     │
│    0    │  2021 │    03   │       3     │
│    0    │  2021 │    03   │       4     │
└─────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────────┘
```

I have gone through the documentation, found some interesting functions, but did not manage to make them solve my problem.
I have never worked with `clickhouse` before and am not very experienced with SQL, which is why I ask here for help.

Comment: Is "week ordinal" relative to start of each month or relative to start of year?

Comment: @datosula: relative to start of each month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
select count() count, toYear(start_of_month) year, toMonth(start_of_month) month,
       toWeek(start_of_week) - toWeek(start_of_month) + 1 AS "week ordinal"
from (
    select *, toStartOfMonth(login_time) start_of_month,
         toStartOfWeek(login_time) start_of_week
    from (
      /* emulate test dataset */
      select data.1 user_id, toDate(data.2) login_time
      from (
        select arrayJoin([
          (1, '2021-02-27'),            
          (1, '2021-02-28'),      
          (1, '2021-03-01'),
          (1, '2021-03-01'),
          (1, '2021-03-02'),
          (2, '2021-03-02'),
          (2, '2021-03-03'),
          (2, '2021-03-08'),
          (2, '2021-03-16'),
          (2, '2021-04-01')]) data)
      )
  )
group by start_of_month, start_of_week
order by start_of_month, start_of_week

/*
┌─count─┬─year─┬─month─┬─week ordinal─┐
│     1 │ 2021 │     2 │            4 │
│     1 │ 2021 │     2 │            5 │
│     5 │ 2021 │     3 │            1 │
│     1 │ 2021 │     3 │            2 │
│     1 │ 2021 │     3 │            3 │
│     1 │ 2021 │     4 │            1 │
└───────┴──────┴───────┴──────────────┘
*/
```